# adb succeeds but sporadically returns exit code 1

Tags: adb, windows

I'm using `adb` in an automated setup for testing. The following commands, whenever I execute them, sporadically return an exit code of `1` with no indication of errors happening:

- `adb shell settings put global bluetooth_disabled_profiles 1`
- `adb shell am force-stop [my app id]`
- `adb shell am start -n [my app id]/[app activity id]`
- `adb forward --remove tcp:8000`

  - interestingly, adding port forwarding using `adb forward tcp:8000 tcp:5050` always returns exit code `0`
- `adb forward --list`
- `adb devices -l`

The exit code of the commands listed above is `0` more than 95% of the time it is executed. In the other 1%…5% of executions, adb returns an exit code of `1` but stderr is empty. In all these cases, the command worked fine, i.e. it seems like `adb` should always return `0`.

I wonder why the exit code is non-zero. Should I get some additional info? Or is this a bug in `adb`? Is this a known issue?

Software info: I've tried different recent versions of `adb` on Windows 10, e.g.:

```
adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 31.0.3-7562133
```

Comment: maybe connection/speed issue. you can check logcat or try linux and check dmesg but I guess the only way to figure out is monitoring serial traffic. does it happen on adb over tcpip too?

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with `adb push` failing for no obvious reason.

It proved to be a problem with the USB-C socket the device was connected to; try a different one?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I'm seeing this issue on a few different computers, Google Pixel smartphones and USB cables, so it does not seem to depend on hardware (alone).